# SQL Server substring to date in a where caluse

Tags: sql-server, substring, where-clause

I'm attempting to take a date contained within a varchar to compare it with getdate() in a where clause. The varchar variable always looks like this:

> Last seen: MM/DD/YY

Some sample data:

```
Last Seen: 07/12/16
Last Seen: 08/01/16
Last Seen: 07/22/16
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
Last Seen: 07/28/16
```

Converting a varchar to datetime and finding the days difference as below works:

```
datediff(day,CAST(substring(CA_NOTE, 12, 8) as datetime), getdate()) as dayspassed
```

The problem is, when I stick this coding in the where clause to compare the date to getdate() I keep getting the same error.

```
where datediff(day,CAST(substring(CA_NOTE, 12, 8) as datetime), getdate()) > 90
```

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

I'm running SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

**Edited to take comments into account**

[destination-data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572928/destination-data)'s suggestion of using TRY_PARSE worked! Thanks everyone.

Comment: can you give us some sample data ?

Comment: Thank you for the comments.

    datediff(day,CAST(substring(CA_NOTE, 12, 8) as datetime), getdate()) > 90

gives the same error message as before.

Comment: ...which means you now have a different question. This new version *looks* ok, so I'll flip back to @GuidoG and his request to show some sample data that we can work with.

Comment: Try using [TRY_PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) instead.  If it returns any nulls the row could not be converted.

Comment: destination-data, this worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not know what to do with `getdate()-90` -- subtract 90 days? 90 minutes? 90 years?

You need to use a function such as `dateadd`, e.g.

```
where convert(varchar(30),cast(substring(CA_NOTE, 12, 8) as datetime),102) < dateadd(dd, -90, getdate())
```

Comment: @bassrek has the fix for your problem. Mine is the fix for your next problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're still converting it to a `VARCHAR`.  Try this instead:

```
CAST(substring(CA_NOTE, 12, 8) as datetime)
```

Comment: Good catch. Multiple problems with this query!